# Sending and receiving UDP packets in LwIP over same connection?

Tags: network-programming, stm32, freertos, lwip

I'm developing an application that should be able to asynchronously transmit and receive UDP messages with the same port number and am a little confused about the best way of doing this. I'm using LwIP and FreeRTOS on a STM32 platform and am wanting to use the netconn api.

My application should:

- Transmit messages after a certain ISR fires. I have it setup so the ISR releases a semaphore, which my UDP task consumes.
- Receive messages all the time

If I were developing this on Linux, I think it'd make sense to have one thread for send and one to receive, or maybe use the `select` OS call. As far as I can tell, neither of these are feasible with LwIP.

The only option I've thought of is to do something like this in my UDP task.

```
void my_task(void)
{
    // setup netconn connection here
    netconn_set_recvtimeout(conn, 1);

    while (1) 
    {
        // Only wait 1ms to take the semaphore
        if(xSemaphoreTake(isr_semaphore, 1) == pdTRUE)
        {
            netconn_send(conn, nbuf);
        }

        // Only block for 1ms to receive a UDP message
        if(netconn_recv(conn, mybuf) == ERR_OK)
        {
            //process incoming data
        }
    }
}
```

However this seems fairly ineloquent to me as I'm wasting 1ms for each call. Is there a better way to achieve the same thing? I feel like this must be a really common requirement, yet I don't see any examples of this out there.

Answer (score 0):

As LWIP documentation mentions netconn API is sequential, so blocking API.
If you want to make it asynchronous you should use raw API which is callback based.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using FreeRTOS, create two separate tasks to send and receive. Set the priority of the sending task higher than that of the listener.
In other words, create a client and a server task.